# python how to get the final destination after redirections

Tags: python, curl, redirect, python-requests

I am analyzing url phishing data, some urls could have several redirections (301, 302).

I can get the final destination and number of redirections using `curl`:

```sh
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w "%{num_redirects},%{url_effective}" <url>
```

Doing the same thing with python `requests`:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

if r.history:
  print(f'{len(r.history)},{r.history[-1].url}')
```

I found that using `requests` `history` doesn't give me the final destination (although the downloaded content is the same respect to `curl`).

For example given the url (this is a legitimate url, I swear) `https://ludik.xyz/music`, this is what I got with `curl`:

```sh
1,https://ludik.herokuapp.com/#/
```

This is what I got in python:

```sh
1,https://ludik.xyz/music
```

How can I get the final destination after all redirections in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final url is set on the response object:

```
In [5]: import requests 
   ...:  
   ...: r = requests.get("https://ludik.xyz/music")                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [8]: r.url                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[8]: 'https://ludik.herokuapp.com/#/'
```