# How to get the final destination URL after redirections in python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, https, python-requests

Response from the actual destination URL is needed.

I have tried solution mentioned [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713731/python-how-to-get-the-final-destination-after-redirections).

```
import requests
doi_link  = 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.artint.2018.07.007'
response = requests.get(url= doi_link ,allow_redirects=True )
print(response.status_code,response.url, response.history)
#Outputs: 200 https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0004370218305988 [<Response [302]>]
```

Why is allow_redirects getting stopped in the middle?

The final URL i get on when done manually on browser is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370218305988?via%3Dihub

I wanted to have this URL programmatically.

**EDIT**
As suggested in comments the final call to the destination is made using JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/9610015)

Comment: If you open the network tools in your browser, you'll see that the last URL is being redirected to with Javascript. You'll have to either parse the response from your `requests` call to get the new URL to redirect to or use something like Selenium so that the browser will handle the redirect.

Comment: @HussainHassam There are no accepted answers there. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @DMalan  Yes i checked the network tools in browser, Could you please point out how to parse requests for redirect URL? I do not want to use Selenium or browser for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested here: [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url/20475712#20475712)

You can use the response history to get the final URL. In this case, the final URL will return a 200, however, it will have the "final final" redirect in the HTML. You can parse the final HTML to get the redirectURL.

I would use something like beautifulsoup4 to make parsing very easy - `pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import unquote
from html import unescape

doi_link  = 'https://doi.org/10.1016/j.artint.2018.07.007'
response = requests.get(url= doi_link ,allow_redirects=True )
for resp in response.history:
     print(resp.status_code, resp.url)

# use final response
# parse html and get final redirect url
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
redirect_url = soup.find(name="input" ,attrs={"name":"redirectURL"})["value"]

# get final response. unescape and unquote url from the HTML
final_url = unescape(unquote(redirect_url))
print(final_url)
article_resp = requests.get(final_url)
```

---

Comment: You don't have to do another request to the final URL (at line `page_text = requests.get(response.url).text`) as far as I know. The `requests` library would already have fetched it for you since you passed in `allow_redirects=True`.

Comment: @HussainHassam Thanks. Got the final URL. 
Not sure why the `article_resp` returned a `<Response [403]>`.

Comment: @DMalan you're absolutely right. i've updated the code to reflect that. thanks!